# Collectors with nested group by for maps (java 8)

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I am trying to process a List which has the following format:
`List<Map<String, Map<String, Item>>` to `Map<String, Map<String, List<Item>>` where `Item` is an object which contains two attributes.

So for the input:

```
[
 <"A1", <"B1", Item_1>>,
 <"A1", <"B1", Item_2>>,
 <"A1", <"B2", Item_3>>,
 <"A2", <"B1", Item_4>>,
 <"A2", <"B2", Item_5>>,
 <"A2", <"B2", Item_6>>
]
```

The output should be:

```
"A1" {
    <"B1", [Item_1, Item_2]>
    <"B2", [Item_3]>
}
"A2" {
    <"B1", [Item_4]>
    <"B2", [Item_5, Item_6]>
}
```

I tried by using:

```
list.stream()
.flatMap(it -> it.entrySet().stream())
.collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValues, Collectors.toList())));
```

but the result is not the desired one, it returns `Map<String, List<Map<String, Item>>>`

```
{
"A1": [
   <"B1", Item_1>,
   <"B1", Item_2>,
   <"B2", Item_3>
  ]
"A2": [
   <"B1", Item_4>,
   <"B2", Item_5>,
   <"B2", Item_6>
  ]
}
```

Can you please advice how can I proceed by grouping also by B_ keys? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed by grouping with `B_` keys if you could have flattened the entries to a triplet data structure. While this is feasible with map entries, it's rather confusing in terms of implementations. A better choice is to create a data structure of your own to temporarily hold those three flattened attributes.

Here is one on the similar lines that I would be using further in the solution.

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Holder {
    String a;
    String b;
    Item c;
}
```

Now the other important point is to ensure you flatten the structure until the innermost entries and not just the outer `Map` as shared in your code. This would require nested `flatMap` to be brought into use.

```
list.stream()
        .flatMap(out -> out.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                        .map(in -> new Holder(e.getKey(), in.getKey(), in.getValue()))))
```

By the end of it, what you would have is a `Stream<Holder>` which can further be grouped twice and mapped to infer the expected result. Here is the complete solution towards that:

```
list.stream()
        .flatMap(out -> out.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                        .map(in -> new Holder(e.getKey(), in.getKey(), in.getValue()))))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Holder::getA,
                Collectors.groupingBy(Holder::getB,
                        Collectors.mapping(Holder::getC,
                                Collectors.toList()))));
```